# How to ignore character special functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So im working on a database in mySQL and i have a attribute with the name "e-mail" and i was wondering is there a way to escape the minus function when inserting etc.

basically when i try to insert such as

```
INSERT INTO users (userName,fName,lName,password,e-mail,PhoneNumber,Address,transactionNumber) 
VALUES('AUserName','FName','LName','Password','Example@gmail.com',55512345,'22 Example lane','34434');
```

I get a error on the insert at the minus in e-mail saying

> Minus operator is not a valid input at this point

Is there a way to escape that or will i have to change the field name?

Comment: How about backticks? `\`e-mail\``?

Comment: This is why when you define your column names in your schema you try to avoid situations like this where they need special treatment. A good schema is a pleasure to work with, a bad one is nothing but frustration. You have some columns with leading capitals, others without, there's no consistency. `phoneNumber` or `TransactionNumber`? `e-mail` or `eMail`? Pick a [naming style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) and stick to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add back ticks to your column name

```
INSERT INTO users (userName,fName,lName,password,`e-mail`,PhoneNumber,Address,transactionNumber) 
VALUES('AUserName','FName','LName','Password','Example@gmail.com',55512345,'22 Example lane','34434');
```